# spark returns error libsnappyjava.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, snappy

I have just extracted and setup spark 1.6.0 into environment that has a fresh install of hadoop 2.6.0 and hive 0.14.

I have verified that hive, beeline and mapreduce works fine on examples.

However, as soon as I run `sc.textfile()` within spark-shell, it returns an error:

```
$ spark-shell
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_67)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala> val textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/snappy-1.1.2-2ccaf764-c7c4-4ff1-a68e-bbfdec0a3aa1-libsnappyjava.so: /tmp/snappy-1.1.2-2ccaf764-c7c4-4ff1-a68e-bbfdec0a3aa1-libsnappyjava.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.<init>(CompressionCodec.scala:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$setConf(TorrentBroadcast.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1326)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:1014)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:1011)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:714)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.hadoopFile(SparkContext.scala:1011)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$textFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:832)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$textFile$1.apply(SparkContext.scala:830)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:714)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:830)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:27)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
        at <init>(<console>:46)
        at .<init>(<console>:50)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/snappy-1.1.2-2ccaf764-c7c4-4ff1-a68e-bbfdec0a3aa1-libsnappyjava.so: /tmp/snappy-1.1.2-2ccaf764-c7c4-4ff1-a68e-bbfdec0a3aa1-libsnappyjava.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1851)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:174)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:152)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:46)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.<init>(CompressionCodec.scala:154)
        ... 69 more
```

There is not a lot in spark's conf. The setup for spark were as per:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_spark/apache_spark_installation.htm

I have already made certain that everything in /tmp is world accessible (uog+rwx).

Any advice/ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

This issue occurs when (for security reasons) `/tmp` is mounted non-exec.  I ran into the same problem and our sysadmin fixed it by remounting `/tmp` as exec.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

More details on [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311438/how-to-make-tmp-executable)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

However, after remounting /tmp with exec, I had to enable 777 on the /tmp. before it eventually worked.
I also did same on all the cluster nodes.

Comment: Got similar error on Hive, It worked for me too:

sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp